# Why does every() method work only one line?

Tags: javascript

The following code works:

```
 let check = checkingImages.every((item)=>item.classList.contains('matched'))
```

But this one doesn't:

```
let check = checkingImages.every((item)=>{
item.classList.contains('matched')
})
```

Can someone explain what's the reason for the second code not working, please?

Comment: If you put `{ }` around the body of a `=>` function, you need an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But why does it work without writing  `return` in forEach() method

Comment: Because `.forEach()` completely ignores values returned from callback functions.